# Sharing with non-administrator account

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have VPS hosting. As I usually do, first thing after I acquire a VPS server, I create a new user, join him to the Administrators group and disable the Administrator account.

First time that I got a VPS from a new company which is very good, but after I logged in with a brand new account, I clicked on folder properties and the sharing tab is GONE!

I tried multiple things to bring it back, such as:

- Check registry if menu entry exists there
- Starting server and workstation services
- Joining new user to users group

Nothing worked. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or why this is happened?

Comment: Have you checked the ACLs for the volume you’re trying to share?

Comment: Server service started? Simple file sharing disabled? (both answers should be YES)

Comment: @BenLavender, can you please extend on ACL or refer me to the materials to read? I am not exactly system administrator.